# How to fix "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'"

Tags: python

```
>>> myList[1]
'from form'
>>> myList[1].append(s)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#144>", line 1, in <module>
    myList[1].append(s)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'
>>>
```

Why is `myList[1]` considered a `'str'` object? `mList[1]` returns the first item in the list `'from form'` but I cannot append to item 1 in the list `myList`.

I need to have a list of lists; so 'from form' should be a list. I did this:

```
>>> myList
[1, 'from form', [1, 2, 't']]
>>> s = myList[1]
>>> s
'from form'
>>> s = [myList[1]]
>>> s
['from form']
>>> myList[1] = s
>>> myList
[1, ['from form'], [1, 2, 't']]
>>>
```

Comment: `mList[1]` returns second item of the `mList`

Comment: Can you check this post: [AttributeError: ‘str’ object has no attribute ‘append’](https://devnote.in/attributeerror-str-object-has-no-attribute-append/)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`myList[1]` is an element of `myList` and its type is string.

`myList[1]` is a string, you can not append to it. `myList` is a list, you should have been appending to it.

```
>>> myList = [1, 'from form', [1,2]]
>>> myList[1]
'from form'
>>> myList[2]
[1, 2]
>>> myList[2].append('t')
>>> myList
[1, 'from form', [1, 2, 't']]
>>> myList[1].append('t')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'
>>>
```

Answer (score 9):

If you want to append a value to `myList`, use `myList.append(s)`.

Strings are immutable -- you can't append to them.

Answer (score 3):

> Why myList[1] is considered a 'str' object?

Because it is a string. What else is `'from form'`, if not a string? (Actually, strings are sequences too, i.e. they can be indexed, sliced, iterated, etc. as well - but that's part of the `str` class and doesn't make it a list or something).

> `mList[1]` returns the first item in the list `'from form'`

If you mean that `myList` is `'from form'`, no it's not!!! The **second** (indexing starts at 0) **element** is `'from form'`. That's a BIG difference. It's the difference between a house and a person.

Also, `myList` doesn't have to be a `list` from your short code sample - it could be anything that accepts `1` as index - a  dict with 1 as index, a list, a tuple, most other sequences, etc. But that's irrelevant.

> but I cannot append to item 1 in the list `myList`

Of course not, because it's a string and you can't append to string. String are immutable. You can concatenate (as in, "there's a new object that consists of these two") strings. But you cannot `append` (as in, "this specific object now has this at the end") to them.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation; now I understand that myList[1] is the string "from form".

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is add additional information to each item in the list that you already created so

```
    alist[ 'from form', 'stuff 2', 'stuff 3']

    for j in range( 0,len[alist]):
        temp= []
        temp.append(alist[j]) # alist[0] is 'from form' 
        temp.append('t') # slot for first piece of data 't'
        temp.append('-') # slot for second piece of data

    blist.append(temp)      # will be alist with 2 additional fields for extra stuff assocated with each item in alist
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple program showing `append('t')` to the list:

```
n=['f','g','h','i','k']

for i in range(1):
    temp=[]
    temp.append(n[-2:])
    temp.append('t')
    print(temp)
```

Output:

```
[['i', 'k'], 't']
```