# Python AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'

Tags: python

I'm trying to find files which are 30 days old in a specific directory, move them to a new folder and compress that folder, however when I execute my script, Python complains about 
***Python AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'***

```
import os 
import time 
import sys 
import shutil 
import tarfile
import sys
import os.path
import _strptime 
from array import*


path="/Data/"
now = time.time()
export = os.path.join(path+"archives")

f=[]
m=[]
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path): #List files in directory 
         for basename in files:
            f.append(os.path.join(root,basename))            
            print(f)
            for i in f:
                mtime=os.stat(i).st_mtime            
                print(i, mtime)
                if mtime > now - 7 * 86400:           
                    m.append(i) 
                    os.makedirs(export,0777)
                    for f in m: 
                        print("moving file", f,  "to",  export)
                        shutil.move(f, export) 
                        tarfile.open(export +time.strftime("%d-%Y-%m") +'.tar.gz', 'w:gz')

                    else:
                        print("Nothing to do")
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4005796/attributeerror-str-object-has-no-attribute-append)

Comment: Because you cannot `append` to a string.

Comment: Next time - don't just put your code here. Show the error message & the specific part in the code that caused it.

Comment: Also, please consider using more descriptive variable names than `f` and `m`!

Comment: Is this all your code? You're not actually calling `.append()` on a string anywhere

Comment: it is actually a good question as it shows the weird (in my opinion) python design principle, where loop variables have more "global" scope than expected and overwrite outer variables

Comment: Hi issue seems to be here f.append(os.path.join(root,basename))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are redeclaring `f` variable. It is a list on the begining, but then used in the inner loop

```
for f in m:
```

which makes `f` a string

simply change a name of inner loop variable to something different like

```
for filename in m: 
    print("moving file", filename,  "to",  export)
    shutil.move(filename, export) 
    tarfile.open(export +time.strftime("%d-%Y-%m") +'.tar.gz', 'w:gz')
```

It is a quite common issue with python, if you declare a variable as the "inner loop variable" it has the same scope as the "outer" loop so it overwrites its values.

```
x = 5
print x #prints 5
for a in range(10):
    for x in range(10):
        y=1
print x #prints 9
sth = [ 1 for x in range(20) ]
print x #prints 19
```