# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'sign'

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-api

When I run my python script, it gives me the following error. Not sure how to resolve it. I think so either the problem is in the version of python, I am using python 3.6 or It could be some packages not included. Please see the included image for error.
 Thanks.
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UWxiY.png)

Code:

```
f = open('c:\ExamCreator\My Project-9352ed298182.json') 
        key = f.read()
        f.close()                                                                             
        credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials(
             'CLIENT_EMAIL', key, 
             scope=
             'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user', 
             sub='amankahlon@test.grasslands.ab.ca'
        )
        http = httplib2.Http()
        http = credentials.authorize(http)                                           
        userinfo = {
            'primaryEmail': 'test1@test.grasslands.ab.ca',
            'name': { 
                'givenName':'John','familyName':'Smith' 
            },
            'password': 'Hello1'
        }
        service = build("admin", "directory_v1", http=http)
        service.users().insert(body=userinfo).execute()
```

Comment: Post all relevant code and errors here directly as text.

Comment: do you have a variable called `signer` declared and assigned to a string?

Comment: Post the code and we can definitely start helping you!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: @PeterDolan I have attached the code

Comment: @JacobIRR I am not making any calls to this method explicitly, Its being triggered here : service = build("admin", "directory_v1", http=http)

Comment: @Carcigenicate Thanks for the response, code is attached.

Comment: Hey @AmanKahlon, thanks for the post. Can you explain where the `build` function is coming from? Is that something you've imported, or perhaps created yourself?

Comment: @PeterDolan build is not created by me, its inbuilt function from one the imported package.

Comment: @PeterDolan its resides in this package from apiclient.discovery import build

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that `signer` is being interpreted as a string, which inherently is just...a string. Not a dict or a list, both of which have attrs. Please post the function that is throwing this error. Also, [this SO question and answer may be relevant to your interests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4005796/attributeerror-str-object-has-no-attribute-append).

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I am not making explicit calls to the sign method. Its being implicitly called by this code service = build("admin", "directory_v1", http=http)